# Swift 4 JSON into array of dictionaries

Tags: ios, arrays, swift4

I have a JSON response like this :

```
[
    {
        "category": C5,
        "group": G43
    },
    {
        "category": C5,
        "group": G43
    },
    {
        "category": C10,
        "group": G1
    },
    {
        "category": C10,
        "group": G1
    },
    {
        "category": C3,
        "group": G1
    },
    {
        "category": C3,
        "group": G1
    },
    {
        "category": C2,
        "group": G3
    },
    {
        "category": C4,
        "group": G3
    }
    ]
```

I need to group the "category" and "group", where the value of them are equal. I want to create dictionary which key is "category" and value is an array of 2 group". results must be like this :

```
[
C5 : [G43]
C10 : [G1]
C3 : [G1, G2]  
C2 : [G3]
C4 : [G3]
]
```

I have created two different classes one for category and one for group and i tried to do it with a for loop and i tried to use `Dictionary(grouping:, by:)`  in the for loop but i think i'm not in a wrong path. do i need to grouping the array two times? How can i do it in a clean way ?

Comment: This is NOT an array of dictionaries in Swift. And what type are Cx? and Gxx?

Comment: They are strings, SO if it's not an array of dictionaries what is it ? @Carpsen90

Comment: @Sattar first code block looks like JSON to me, not swift. (Swift uses `[:]` for dictionaries, not `{:}`).

Comment: @Jasarien thanks, it was an honest mistake, yes it is JSON, i will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than trying to work with dictionaries, try converting them into a type that actually represents what the data is…

```
struct Something {
    let category: String
    let group: String
}

let array = [Something(category:  "C5", group: "G43"),
             Something(category:  "C5", group: "G43"),
             Something(category:  "C10", group: "G1"),
             Something(category:  "C10", group: "G1"),
             Something(category:  "C3", group: "G1"),
             Something(category:  "C3", group: "G2"),
             Something(category:  "C2", group: "G3"),
             Something(category:  "C4", group: "G3")]

let groups = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0.category} )

group.forEach { key, somethings in
    print(key)
    print(somethings.map({$0.group}))
}

C10
["G1", "G1"]
C3
["G1", "G2"]
C5
["G43", "G43"]
C2
["G3"]
C4
["G3"]
```

---

*edit*

If you want to remove duplicate groups…

```
group.forEach { key, somethings in
    print(key)
    print(Set(somethings.map({$0.group})))
}

C3
["G1", "G2"]
C2
["G3"]
C4
["G3"]
C5
["G43"]
C10
["G1"]
```

and if you *really* want to use dictionaries, and lose the type safety and autocompletion that comes with a a struct…

```
let array = [["category":  "C5", "group": "G43"],
             ["category":  "C5", "group": "G43"],
             ["category":  "C10", "group": "G1"],
             ["category":  "C10", "group": "G1"],
             ["category":  "C3", "group": "G1"],
             ["category":  "C3", "group": "G2"],
             ["category":  "C2", "group": "G3"],
             ["category":  "C4", "group": "G3"]]

let group = Dictionary(grouping: array, by: {$0["category"]} )

group.map { key, somethings in
    print(key!)
    print(Set(somethings.map({$0["group"]!})))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but you have grouped the groups i need to group the Categories to, for example in your answer C10 must have only one G1 ...

Comment: Your data has two C10/G1 dictionaries